# What is the "protection circle" in Tumbbad made of?

Tags: tumbbad

I have understood that Vinayak Rao feeds dolls made of flour to Hastar. I haven't understood what is the substance that he used to make the protection circle. Surely, both the substance used to make the doll and the protection circle can't be flour.

Comment: Please add to your question a reason _why knowing is important to understanding or appreciating the movie_.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-come-Hastar-in-Tumbbad-be-able-to-eat-dolls-of-flour-even-though-he-burns-even-on-the-slight-touch-of-flour

Comment: Circle was made of flour too, I think  it's more ir what is offered to him as doll or prohibited to him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circle was made of flour. Here's why,

Go back to scene where Vinayak has taken Pandurang(his son) into Goddesses' womb to practice their act, while Pandurang makes protection circle with flour this is their conversation:

> PANDURANG makes a protective circle with the flour on
> the heaving floor.
>
> VINAYAK: Yeh Lakshman-Rekha ki tarah hai. Hastar isse paar nahi kar sakta. *[This is like forbidden line. Hastar cannot cross this.]*
>
> PANDURANG: Aur kiya toh? *[And what if he did?]*
>
> VINAYAK: Bhasm ho jayega. Yaad kar... Sona toh utha liya tha usne Devi ka, par anaaj nahi utha paya tha...Issi liye usse iss aate ki bhook bhi hai, aur darr bhi. *[Then he will burn to ashes. Remember! He took the Goddesses' gold but wasn't able to take foodgrains, that's why he has hunger for food as well as fear of it.]*

This is evident from the final scene where one "copy" of Hastar turns to ashes when it crosses the protection circle(sphere).

[image]